# How to remove duplicate elements from 2 XML files?

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have a XML that I am parsing to my database, this XML size is about 10MB, and it contains few millions of elements.

Every 30-60 seconds its being updated, but only several elements, not all of it.

In order to parse it in the fastest way to the database, I developed a function to remove the duplicate elements from the 2 XML files, here's the code:

```
XDocument doc2 = XDocument.Parse(tempDoc.ToString());

var doc1 = new XDocument();
try
{
doc1 = XDocument.Load(bookieName + ".xml");
}
catch
{ }

try
{
var dict1 = doc1.Descendants("event").Select(el => el.ToString()).ToList();
var dict2 = doc1.Descendants("event").Select(el => el.ToString()).ToList();

foreach (var elem in dict1)
{
    if (dict2.Contains(elem))
    {
    if (dict2.Find(x => x == elem).ToString() == dict1.Find(x => x == elem).ToString())
    {
        doc2.Descendants("event").Where(x => x.ToString() == elem).Remove();
    }
    }
}
}
catch (Exception e)
{
Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}

return doc2;
```

The problem is, it works great for small XML files, but for large XML files (10MB) it takes 100% CPU for 2-5 minutes.

Do you have any idea how can I improve it and make it better?

I am kinda hopeless.

Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't be line "var dict2 = doc1.Descendants(..." be "var dict2 = doc2.Descendants(..." ? Now both dict1 and dict2 contains the same elements from doc1

Comment: Can you provide an example of an event node?  Your code is terribly inefficient and a large part of that is driven by the fact you are using the entire xml string for comparison as opposed to a single (or multiple) attributes.

Comment: The XML sample can be found here: http://pastebin.com/fCErUrHP. I had to upload it because it was too large. how would you do that?

Comment: So I'm guessing what you'd actually like is for events with distinct 'id's, correct?

Comment: I'd like to compare the event element and check if there's any changes in the child-elements. the ID should be unique, yes.

Comment: So if two elements have the same id but different children, keep both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you only wish to remove elements in `doc2` if they also exist in `doc1`, but not the other way around.

The issue you're facing is that you're performing very inefficient searches. If you have a few million records you're effectively searching though a few million *squared* records.

Instead you should use dictionaries, rather than lists, to vastly speed up your algorithm.

Try this:

```
var dict1 = doc1.Descendants("event").ToDictionary(x => x.ToString(), x => x);
var dict2 = doc2.Descendants("event").ToDictionary(x => x.ToString(), x => x);

var xs = dict1.Keys.Intersect(dict2.Keys).Select(x => dict2[x]);

foreach (var x in xs)
{
    x.Remove();
}

return doc2;
```

Yes, that's it. I've tested this on some dummy data ad it worked fine.

doc1:

```
<doc>
  <event>bar</event>
  <event>foo</event>
</doc>
```

Initial doc2:

```
<doc>
  <event>foo</event>
  <event>qaz</event>
</doc>
```

Final doc2:

```
<doc>
  <event>qaz</event>
</doc>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to solve by just by checking if the element exists in the database before you add it.

And you want to use an xml reader so you can parse while you read (for optimal performance)

Comment: Tried it, worked really bad, the XML is really huge and I dont want to "kill" my DB by sending unneeded queries, if an element is already exists in the DB, I dont want to re-send it. I want to add to the DB only the new elements.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're fighting two things:

1. XML is a poor choice for this kind of task (but I understand that it's probably not your choice)
2. Reading the whole document into an `XDocument` (or `XmlDocument`) is expensive and not necessary

To get rid of (2), try using a lower level approach with `XmlReader` (which may not be enough) or an even lower level like Java-nese `SAX` or Perl-ish `XML:Twig` which give you event-based XML parsing without building the document structure - <strike>but I'm not aware of such libraries for .net.</strike> There's a [port of the SAX parser for .NET](http://saxdotnet.sourceforge.net/), but I don't know how good it is.

Of course, you can save much time keeping the data from previously parsed document and only parse the new one (but I'm sure you know that)

Comment: Thanks for your replay, regarding 1, you are right, I am downloading 3rd party xml file... basically thats what I am doing, I am downloading and saving the file, when I download again, I compare it to the one I already downloaded and running the code I posted in my question. then I get a small XML file with only the delta, but it takes to long to run... :\

can you maybe give a code samples for your solutions?

Answer (score 0):

What you do now is, that for each of these millions events in dict1 you iterate over millions of events in dict2, comparing every event from dict1 with every event from dict2. This makes thousands of billions of comparisons! This is not necessary. Put all events from first XML to dictionary. Then for each event in the second XML look into dictionary whether the same event exists in first XML too. If it does, remove it. Searching in dictionary is much much faster than going through each of millions events in first XML and will make your program much faster too.